# App unresponsive while WebView is loading in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I was trying to add a Webview to my app today and I noticed that while the URL is loading, the whole app becomes unresponsive.
I tried the Microsoft XAML Gallery and it was working fine there so I must be missing something even though I couldn't see anything special in the code.

Any idea what could be causing this?

P.S: I'm only providing the URL to the Webview in XAML but I also tried doing so in code after the page loads.

EDIT: Added code snippet

```
<WebView x:Name="webView1" Grid.Row="1" Source="https://mail.ovh.net/roundcube/" NavigationStarting="webView1_NavigationStarting" NavigationCompleted="webView1_NavigationCompleted"/>
```

Comment: I can’t reproduce your issue. Could you please provide your code snippet about how to use webView?

Comment: Edited the post. It's just the Xaml tag with a source, nothing else. Everytime the webview is loading a page the whole UI freezes

Comment: Your code works well on my PC, could you please try to create a  new project to test?